# Python logging module doesn't work in Sagemaker

Tags: python, logging, amazon-sagemaker

I've got a sagemaker instance running a jupyter notebook.  I'd like to use python's logging module to write to a log file, but it doesn't work.

My code is pretty straightforward:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s", datefmt="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
fhandler = logging.FileHandler("taxi_training.log")
fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fhandler)

logger.debug("starting log...")
```

This should write a line to my file taxi_training.log but it  doesn't.

I tried using the reload function from importlib, I also tried setting the output stream to sys.stdout explicitly.  Nothing is logging to the file or in cloudwatch.

Do I need to add anything to my Sagemaker instance for this to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

The Python logging module requires a logging level and one or more handlers to process output. By default, the logging level is set to WARNING (30) with a STDOUT handler for that level. If a logging level and/or handler is not explicitly defined, these settings are inherited from the parent root logger settings. These settings can be verified by adding the following lines to the bottom of your code:

```
# Verify levels and handlers
print("Parent Logger: "+logger.parent.name)
print("Parent Level: "+str(logger.parent.level))
print("Parent Handlers: "+str(logger.parent.handlers))
print("Logger Level: "+str(logger.level))
print("Logger Handlers: "+str(logger.handlers))
```

The easiest way to instantiate a handler and set a logging level is by running the logging.basicConfig() function (documentation). This will set a logging level and STDOUT handler at the root logger level which will propagate to any child loggers created in the same code. Here is an example using the code provided:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('log')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) # Set logging level and STDOUT handler

logger.info(5)
```

Comment: This answered it for me. I had also setup a logger and was logging INFO level, but hadn't reset the level to log to stdout as info. This worked and info logs now show up in my CloudWatch logs
```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```